# Laravel web socket ssl assignment

Tags: laravel, ssl, websocket, certificate, plesk

I am using Laravel web sockets. I can't find path local_cert and local_pk I can't define ssl. I am using  lets encrypt ssl.

When I create SSL, it just creates a certificate as .pert. What should I do for the .crt and .key? How can I find a way?

I'm giving ssl over Plesk

Comment: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/232#issuecomment-521247753

Comment: i did but it didn't  error: app.js:39150 WebSocket connection to 'wss://sub.xsite.com.tr/app/abc?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.4.0&flash=false' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404